# Qt: Accessing a public object from another window

Tags: c++, qt

This program is supposed to create the object `mBulbPrimary` of the class `pointCloudBool` in the main window and perform calculations which change the content of that object. When clicking the `actionSave_Mandelbulb` widget a new window `DialogSaveMB` appears and the user can enter a filepath and click the `pushButton_save` button. This is supposed to call the `mBulbPrimary.savePrimary(filePath)` function of the original object.

However in *dialogsavemb.cpp* the mBulbPrimary object is not recogized and I don't understand why. The object is public and *mainwindow.h* is included in *dialogsavemb.cpp* so why can't it access the object or its methods/functions?

mainwindow.h:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include "dialogsavemb.h"
#include "pointcloudbool.h"


QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class DialogSaveMB;
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

    DialogSaveMB dialogSaveMB;  //Dialog window

    pointCloudBool mBulbPrimary;  //public mBulbPrimary object
private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;


private slots:
    //unrelated functions...

    void openSaveMBulbWindow();
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QDialog>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    //unrelated connections...

    connect(ui->actionSave_Mandelbulb, SIGNAL(triggered(bool)),
            this, SLOT(openSaveMBulbWindow()));

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

//Implementation:

//unrelated functions...

void MainWindow::openSaveMBulbWindow(){
    dialogSaveMB.show();

}
```

dialogsavemb.h:

```
#ifndef DIALOGSAVEMB_H
#define DIALOGSAVEMB_H

#include <QDialog>

namespace Ui {
class DialogSaveMB;
}

class DialogSaveMB : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit DialogSaveMB(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~DialogSaveMB();

private:
    Ui::DialogSaveMB *ui;

private slots:
    void saveMBulb(std::string filePath);
};

#endif // DIALOGSAVEMB_H
```

dialogsavemb.cpp:

```
#include "dialogsavemb.h"
#include "ui_dialogsavemb.h"
#include "mainwindow.h"

DialogSaveMB::DialogSaveMB(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::DialogSaveMB)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->radioButton_txt->setChecked(true);

    //Get filepath from a lineEdit widget of the dialog:
    std::string filePath = ui->lineEdit_filePath->text().toUtf8().constData();

    //unrelated connections...

    connect(ui->pushButton_save, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)),
            this, SLOT(saveMBulb(filePath)));

}

DialogSaveMB::~DialogSaveMB()
{
    delete ui;
}

void DialogSaveMB::saveMBulb(std::string filePath){
    mBulbPrimary.savePrimary(filePath);
    //The above line needs to access the 'mBulbPrimary' object in the MainWindow class
    //but it can't.
}
```

Comment: Qt way to solve this is, have the dialog just emit a signal with the file name in `saveMBulb`. Then in MainWindow, connect this signal to a slot which handles the file name.

Comment: I thought that too but couldn't figure out how to point from the dialog to the window.

Comment: When you create the dialog object (happens in MainWindows constructor here, automatically), just connect whatever signals you need.

Comment: Do you mean to make the connection inside of *mainwindow.cpp*? I guess that makes sense but I think that I don't understand pointers (or whatever is needed here) well enough. I wrote this into *mainwindow.cpp* which doesn't work:  `connect(dialogSaveMB.ui->pushButton_save, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)),
            this, SLOT(saveMBulb(filePath)));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably what @hyde is describing in the comments:

In mainwindow.h add:

```cpp
private slots:
  void saveMBulb(const QString &filePath);
```

In mainwindow.cpp `MainWindow` constructor add:

```cpp
  connect(&dialogSaveMB, &DialogSaveMB::mBulbPathChanged, this, &MainWindow::saveMBulb);
```

In mainwindow.cpp add:

```cpp
void MainWindow::saveMBulb(const QString &filePath)
{
  // you could add some checks here, eg. !filePath.isEmpty() or QFileInfo(filePath).exists()
  mBulbPrimary.savePrimary(filePath.toStdString());
}
```

In dialogsavemb.h add:

```cpp
signals:
  void mBulbPathChanged(const QString &filePath) const;
```

In dialogsavemb.cpp `DialogSaveMB` constructor, change:

```cpp
  //connect(ui->pushButton_save, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(saveMBulb(filePath)));

  connect(ui->pushButton_save, &QPushButton::clicked, this, [this]() {
    emit mBulbPathChanged(ui->lineEdit_filePath->text());
  });
```

You do *not* need to include `minwindow.h` in the `DialogSaveMB` code. This is poor practice anyway since it creates a circular dependency (MainWindow need the dialog header, and the dialog needs MainWindow header -- not ideal).

And `mBulbPrimary` does not need to be public.